# How can I display images retrieved with AJAX in an application built with Laravel?

Tags: ajax, laravel-10

I'm retrieving data from a product using Laravel and displaying it via AJAX. Although I'm getting the correct paths for the images, they aren't being displayed. How can I solve this problem so that the images are displayed correctly? Because ajax shows me the path to the images and the name of the image.

```
// Data report for products
fetchDataProducts();

function fetchDataProducts() {
    $('#tableProducts').DataTable({
        buttons: ['excel'],
        destroy: true,
        columns: [
            {
                title: 'Nom du produit',
                data: 'product_name'
            },
            {
                title: 'Description',
                data: 'product_description'
            },
            {
                title: 'Catégorie',
                data: 'product_category_name',
            },
            {
                title: 'Prix',
                data: 'product_price'
            },
            {
                title: 'Image',
                data: 'product_image',
            },
            {
                title: 'Action',
                data: 'btn_actions'
            },
        ],
        processing: true,
        ajax: {
            type: 'post',
            data: {
                _token: csrf_token
            },
            url: '/product/getProductList',
        },
        lengthMenu: [
            [10, 25, 50, 100, -1],
            [10, 25, 50, 100, "Tout"]
        ],
    });
}


// Show modal for product
function showModalProductForm(productID = null) {
    if (productID) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/product/find",
            data: {
                product_id: productID,
                _token: csrf_token
            },
            success: function (resp) {
                $('#productID').val(resp.product_id);
                $('#productName').val(resp.product_name);
                $('#productDescription').val(resp.product_description);
                $('#productCategoryID').val(resp.product_category_id);
                $('#productPrice').val(resp.product_price);
                // Handle image preview if needed
                $('#productImagePreview').attr('src', resp.product_image).show();

                $('.btnStoreProduct').attr("url", "/product/update");

                $('#productFormRef').modal({
                    backdrop: 'static',
                    keyboard: false,
                    show: true
                });
            },
            error: function (resp) {
                console.log(resp);
                notify({
                    type: 'error',
                    title: 'Produit',
                    message: resp.responseJSON
                });
            }
        });
        return;
    }
    // Clear form fields
    $('#productID').val('');
    $('#productName').val('');
    $('#productDescription').val('');
    $('#productCategoryID').val('');
    $('#productPrice').val('');
    $('#productImage').val('');
    // Reset image preview if needed
    $('#productImagePreview').attr('src', '').hide();

    // Adjust the URL for create
    $('.btnStoreProduct').attr("url", "/product/store");

    // Show modal
    $('#productFormRef').modal({
        backdrop: 'static',
        keyboard: false,
        show: true
    });
}


/**
 * On click to store product
 */
$('.btnStoreProduct').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let url = $(this).attr("url");
    const icon = $(this).attr("icon");
    const btnCreate = '.iconBtnCreate';
    const productID = $('#productID').val();
    const productName = $('#productName').val();
    const productDescription = $('#productDescription').val();
    const productCategoryID = $('#productCategoryID').val();
    const productPrice = $('#productPrice').val();
    const productImage = $('#productImage')[0].files[0];

    if (!productName) {
        notify({
            type: 'error',
            title: 'Produit',
            message: "Veuillez renseigner tous les champs obligatoires (*)"
        });
        return;
    }

    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('product_name', productName);
    formData.append('product_description', productDescription);
    formData.append('product_category_id', productCategoryID);
    formData.append('product_price', productPrice);
    formData.append('product_image', productImage);
    formData.append('_token', csrf_token);

    if (productID) {
        formData.append('product_id', productID);
    }

    $(btnCreate).removeClass(icon);
    $(btnCreate).addClass("fa-spinner fa-spin");

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: formData,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function (resp) {
            if (resp.response === "success") {
                notify({
                    type: 'success',
                    title: 'Produit',
                    message: 'Opération effectuée avec succès!'
                });

                // Clear form fields
                $('#productID').val('');
                $('#productName').val('');
                $('#productDescription').val('');
                $('#productCategoryID').val('');
                $('#productPrice').val('');
                $('#productImage').val('');
                // Reset image preview if needed
                $('#productImagePreview').attr('src', '').hide();

                $(btnCreate).addClass(icon);
                $(btnCreate).removeClass("fa-spinner fa-spin");

                // Hide modal
                $('#productFormRef').modal('hide');

                // Refresh data table
                fetchDataProducts();
            } else {
                notify({
                    type: 'error',
                    title: 'Produit',
                    message: 'Une erreur est survenue lors de l\'enregistrement!'
                });
                $(btnCreate).addClass(icon);
                $(btnCreate).removeClass("fa-spinner fa-spin");
            }
        },
        error: function (resp) {
            $(btnCreate).addClass(icon);
            $(btnCreate).removeClass("fa-spinner fa-spin");
            console.log(resp);
            notify({
                type: 'error',
                title: 'Produit',
                message: resp.responseJSON
            });
        }
    });

    
});
```

Comment: Did you inspect the images in your browser? What are their `src` attributes, are they correct? Does the image show when you enter it in your address bar?

Comment: yes, images exist. I use datatable from AdminLte.

Comment: And "_what are their src attributes_"? Can you post an example? Did you check permissions of the files?

Comment: storage/public/product_images                  but when I open the console, I come across something like http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/product_image/b03lTmZdABYsSZ9ReVmEquT766vtKUhN6MxKHlim.jpg. 

and clicking tells me 404 NOT FOUND

Comment: Either use `/storage/public...`, the `asset()` helper or prepend your host to the url. Did you run `php artisan storage:link`? Make sure there are not errors/404 in your DevConsole. Good luck

Comment: with this, I no longer get errors in the console, but the javascript only retrieves the path and that's what it displays.